# embedded sql in c,how to check if records exist

Tags: c, embedded-sql

I have tried these:

```
1.if (EXEC SQL EXIST SELECT ...)
2.EXEC SQL IF EXIST SELECT ...
```

but none of these work,any help?

Comment: where is the C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the count and check whether it is zero. Something along this line:

```
int a;
EXEC SQL SELECT count(*) INTO :a
         FROM some_table
         WHERE some_condition;
if (a != 0)...
```